# How do I find a tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a German Billiard League website for results, to tabulate and submit to a rating system that requires a certain format. I am no python expert, but I have muddled through how to pull a complete list of links from the root League page, and to get Date, Home/Visitor teams, and now I am trying to capture individual match data.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3" nowrap="" rowspan="2" width="100"><b>
                                Spiel 2<br/>8-Ball                      </b>
</td>
<td class="home up" colspan="6" valign="top">Christian Fachinger</td>
<td class="visitor up" colspan="7" valign="top">Michael Schneider</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="home down" colspan="6" valign="top">7</td>
<td class="visitor down" colspan="7" valign="top">4</td>
```

Site: https://hbu.billardarea.de/cms_leagues/matchday/344947

I am trying to find the "td" tag that contains the text string "Spiel 2". I should then be able to pull the game - "8-ball", and then move on to figuring out how to capture the data inside the relevant "class" tags. For the life of me, I cannot get a result back. I have tried many permutations of various soup commands, but either get a "None", or "[]". I "think" it might have something to do with the extra spaces, but have tried various regex-centric commands, but have not been able to "select" this td tag to do further data gathering.

What am I doing wrong? I know I am not coding this in the most efficient manner, and this is the first time I have tried to write a web scraper, and in general, am a python newb.

'''

```
import requests
import re
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://hbu.billardarea.de/cms_leagues/plan/7870/10406"

def import_all_links():
    page = requests.get(URL).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    path = soup.select("a[href*=matchday]")

    for link in path:
        file1 = open("league.txt", "a")  # append mode
        file1.write("https://hbu.billardarea.de" + link['href'] + '\n')
        file1.close()

def get_date():
    links_file = open(r'C:\Users\Russ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.10\league.txt', "r") 
    for day_link in links_file:
        day_link = day_link.rstrip("\n")
        soup = requests.get(day_link).text
        day_links_parse = BeautifulSoup(soup, "html.parser")
        date = day_links_parse.select('label:contains(Datum)')
        league = day_links_parse.select('label:contains(Saison)')
        home = day_links_parse.find(attrs={"class": "home"}).text
        home = home.partition(":")[2]
        visitor = day_links_parse.find(attrs={"class": "visitor"}).text
        visitor = visitor.partition(":")[2]
        print(day_links_parse)
        **play_table = day_links_parse.td.find_all(text = re.compile('Spiel 2'))**  <<<<< Issue
        **print(play_table)**                                                 <<<<< Returns 0 results

        for item in date:
            date = item.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
            date = date.partition(" ")[0]
            date = date.split(".")
            date = date[1] + "\\" + date[0] + "\\" + date[2]
        for item in league:
            league = item.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
            league = league.partition(" ")[0]

        print(date, ",", league, ",", home, " (H) vs ", visitor, "(V)", sep='')

import_all_links()
get_date() '''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, for example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://hbu.billardarea.de/cms_leagues/matchday/344947")
table_rows = (
    BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    .select(".report_table, .matchday_table, .score_table > tr")
)

spiel_zwei = table_rows[5].select_one("b").getText(strip=True, separator=" ")
heim, gast = [spieler.getText() for spieler in table_rows[5].select("td")[1:]]
spielergebnis = table_rows[6].getText(strip=True, separator=" vs. ")

print(f"{spiel_zwei}\n{heim} - {gast}\n{spielergebnis}")
```

Output:

```
Spiel 2 8-Ball
Rolf Berghöfer - Zühtü Uyanik
6 vs. 7
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This code worked great! I can't profess to fully understand how that data was pulled out, however.. What if I want to pull out "Spiel 3", and the associated fields? I am not quite sure how you landed on the correct table rows?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re
import pandas as pd


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = get_soup(r.text)
        urls = [urljoin(url, x['href'])
                for x in soup.select('a[href*=matchday]')]
        allin = []
        for link in urls:
            r = req.get(link)
            soup = get_soup(r.text).select_one('#main_frontend')
            match = soup.find(text=re.compile('Spiel 2'))
            allin.append(
                {
                    'Date': soup.select('.nochange')[3].text.split()[0],
                    'League': soup.select('.nochange')[1].text.split()[1],
                    'Home': soup.select_one('.home').text.split(':')[1],
                    'Visitor': soup.select_one('.visitor').text.split(':')[1],
                    'Game': list(match.next_elements)[1].strip(),
                    'Whom': [x.text for x in match.find_all_next('td')[:2]],
                    'Result': [x['colspan'] for x in match.find_all_next('td')[:2]]
                }
            )

        df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
        print(df)


main('https://hbu.billardarea.de/cms_leagues/plan/7870/10406')
```

Output:

```
         Date       League  ...                                    Whom  Result
0  11.09.2021  (2021/2022)  ...          [Rolf Berghöfer, Zühtü Uyanik]  [6, 7]
1  11.09.2021  (2021/2022)  ...     [Christian Roller, Balthasar Nebel]  [6, 7]
2  11.09.2021  (2021/2022)  ...  [Peter Graessner, Christian Fachinger]  [6, 7]

[3 rows x 7 columns]
```